# Does "Design Resolution Size" affect how sprites created using OpenGL renders them on screen?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, cocos2d-x

In cocos2d-x, there is the the concept of "Design Resolution Size", which lets you pick the appropriate asset, depending on the size of the screen, and you can apply the appropriate content scaling factor.

Here is the problem:

I draw a 2d Sin Curve by passing in a set of vertices. These vertices are computed for a screen of 480x320.

What happens when I run it on a device which has a resolution of 1920x1200, even though the design resolution is set to 480x320 ? Do I have to recompute the vertices so that the same number of crests / troughs are seen on the higher resolution device, or is there some way to do this without extra computation ?

I don't have any more devices to test this, so I don't know how to figure this out.

EDIT: I now use cocos2d-x v3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After purchasing and testing this on a number of devices with cocos2d-x v3, I find that scaling is handled automatically. Regardless of the resolution of the actual device, my openGl draw commands seem to result in the same output on all devices. It appears that cocos2d-x does something internally, so things looks the same on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

Anything drawn directly/solely with OpenGL will bypass/ignore any and all cocos2d internal settings and code paths, such as design resolution.

You can always use a simulator to test your resolution-specific code. For iOS the simulator comes with Xcode, for Android use the [Emulator](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/emulator.html).

Comment: So are you saying that if I compute the vertices for a sin curve with a single crest and trough occupying the entire screen (like a horizontal S) for a 480x320 device, then on a larger screen (1920x1080) it won't occupy the whole screen ? (I'm overriding the draw method)